# How to remove "View Problems (Alt+F8)" in monaco-editor 0.25.2?

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way to disable this UI?

[image: the thing I want to remove]

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any configuration to do so, but this CSS rule works for me. I am using 0.29.1:

```
.monaco-editor .hover-row.status-bar {
  display: none;
}
```